# InfluxDB. Big time range with where clause by field performance issue

Tags: performance, influxdb

I have next schema (and a lot more field columns).

| time | projectId (tag) | rank (field) | score (field) | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1647009697988 | 21345-asdfg-2345-asd | 1 | 10 | 23456 |
| 1647346711847 | 234-dfg-34-sdfg | 2 | 5 | 34567 |
| ...more | ...more | ...more | ...more | ...more |

My query is:

```
select sum("duration") as "duration" from "measurement1" where time > 3_month_back_time() and time < now() and "projectId"='21345-asdfg-2345-asd' and rank>=1 and rank<=5 and score>=6 and score<=9 fill(null)
```

So, I have more than 100k records stored and with time there will be more. The problem is that query is really slow (~30 seconds) when date range is > "last 3 month". I want to filter even more (last 6 month, last year).

I assume it is because I apply **where** clause to **field** values.
One way is to move **fields** to **tags** so I can use built-in index mechanism, but I have "infinite" amount of rank, score, duration values.

Any suggestion on how can I speed up the query?